# optimization ng-repeat in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a json file .

```
{"records":
[
{"masp":"CPUIT5","loai":"cpu","hangsx":"INTEL","tensp":"CPU INTEL CORE I5","gia":"8789000"}
,{"masp":"CPUIT7","loai":"cpu","hangsx":"INTEL","tensp":"CPU INTEL CORE I7","gia":"12300495"},
{"masp":"CPUXE5","loai":"cpu","hangsx":"INTEL","tensp":"CPU XEON E5 2600 V5","gia":"99567600"},
{"masp":"VGAASTI","loai":"vga","hangsx":"GIGABYTE","tensp":"VGA GTX Gigabyte 1080Ti","gia":"20999000"},
{"masp":"VGARX48","loai":"vga","hangsx":"AMD","tensp":"VGA RADEON RX480","gia":"12900000"},
{"masp":"VGARX46","loai":"vga","hangsx":"AMD","tensp":"VGA RADEON RX460","gia":"5600000"}
]}
```

I use ng-repeat to show it in html , but I only want show loai=cpu . What can I do . Here is my code

```
ng-repeat="data in vm.mydata " ng-show="data.loai=='cpu'"
```

But veryslow . Is there a way to optimize it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter your data in your JavaScript rather than in HTML

```
$scope.filtered = data.records.filter(function (element) {
    return element.loai === 'cpu'
});
```

HTML

```
ng-repeat="data in filtered" //won't have extra DOM checking vs using ng-show
```

Answer (score 0):

Appreciate above answer.But we can simply also do this.

```
<div ng-repeat= "record in records | filter: { loai:'cpu' } ">
 <span>{{ record.loai}}</span>
```